# How to checkout from HEAD revision of all svn tagged externals

Tags: svn

Here all the externals are tagged

svn pg svn:externals .

ABC ht*p://svn.apache.org/src/svnrt/ABC/tags/ABC_3.114/ABC
DEF ht*p://svn.apache.org/src/svnrt/DEF/tags/DEF_1.97/DEF
XYZ ht*p://svn.apache.org/src/svnrt/XYZ/tags/XYZ_1.251/XYZ

Can I checkout from the HEAD revision of all externals instead of going each tagged build and doing a switch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Update your `svn:externals` property to point to the trunk instead of to the tag.

Using your example:

```
ABC http://svn.apache.org/src/svnrt/ABC/trunk/ABC
DEF http://svn.apache.org/src/svnrt/DEF/trunk/DEF
XYZ http://svn.apache.org/src/svnrt/XYZ/trunk/XYZ
```